# Matching items in an array then display, using Jquery

Tags: jquery, matching

I have this function where I am getting the name of a Venue:

```
var VenueNames = [];
var TipPlaceName = [];
var Tip = [];
function jsonData(){
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {
        for(var i = 0; i < results.response.checkins.items.length; i++) {   
            var name = results.response.checkins.items[i].venue.name;
            VenueNames.push(name);
            }

        } 
    });
};
```

here is my other function, which gives me "Tips" the user left along with the name of the Venue the "Tips" where left at.

```
function tips(){
    $.ajax({
    url: urltips,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {

        for(var i = 0; i < results.response.tips.items.length; i++) {
                var tip = results.response.tips.items[i].text;
                var tipVenueName = results.response.tips.items[i].venue.name;
                Tip.push(tip);
                TipPlaceName.push(tipVenueName);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I need to match up the venue names from the first function and if they match, use the tips that are associated with the matching Venue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try using an object instead?

```
var VenueTips = new Object();
function jsonData(){
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {
        for(var i = 0; i < results.response.checkins.items.length; i++) {   
            var name = results.response.checkins.items[i].venue.name;
            VenueTips[name]=true;
            }

        } 
    });
};
function tips(){
    $.ajax({
    url: urltips,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {

        for(var i = 0; i < results.response.tips.items.length; i++) {
                var tip = results.response.tips.items[i].text;
                var tipVenueName = results.response.tips.items[i].venue.name;
                if(VenueTips[tipVenueName]===true){
                   VenueTips[tipVenueName] = tip;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```